# How to download a file to a certain location with OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, apache

I'm trying to download a file at a certain URL by getting the URL from a TextView.

I've set an OnItemClickListener for the ListView (it contains TextView objects), but when I run the app, click on the URL in the ListView, nothing happens. I think the problem lies in the getAlbumStorageDir() method. I'm not sure what string should be passed into the method. What is an albumName? I've read the Android developer tutorial for this method, but am still confused. In case the problem lies in the other method, I've included both:

Here's the code onItemclick() method:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
    {
        TextView temp = (TextView) view;
            if (isExternalStorageWritable() == true) 
            {
            try {
                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(temp.toString()), getAlbumStorageDir("download"));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }


    }
```

Here is the getAlbumStorageDir() method:

```
public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName) 
    {
        // Get the directory for the user's public music directory. 
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), albumName);
        if (!file.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e("SearchActivity", "Directory not created");
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if the button is being clicked. i.e put a toast message in there to check...

Comment: No I have not. Will do and report back.

Comment: It is indeed being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Within your listener's try/catch, I'm not entirely sure what

```
    temp.toString()
```

is going to provide for you, but if it's the text of the textview you want, try

```
    temp.getText()
```

instead.

Comment: toString is what I want. It returns a string element what is what is what is to be passed into the URL class constructor. getText() returns a char sequence. I guess I could cast to string and see what happens...don't think that's the issue though.

Comment: temp.getText().toString();

Comment: @greenapps So what does temp.toString() return? Appears to be the same as what I had before with an extra step. Tried your suggestion, same result.